# Running a macro from another macro in XTRF

Tags: xtrf

How to run one macro from another macro with parameters?

I have been able to run a macro from another macro using the MacroService methos `runMacro(list, macro)`, but it only returns bytes and can't take parameters.

So far I've been looking at the MacroService trying to run a MacroRequest both sync and async. The sync just fails the macro, but working with the ActionEntry from the async method hasn't worked either. Here I've tried to use the class SpringAsynchActionAdapter to create an AsynchAction using

```
SpringAsynchActionAdapter.create(actionEntry, com.radzisz.xtrf.service.macro.ExecuteMacroAction, macroRequest);
```

With this I get an AsynchAction which I can execute, but it just fails.

I have been seeing some stuff regarding the services to use @Autowire, but I can't seem to get it to work with XTRF.